# DataTable isnt editable after i switch the tabs

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm nesting a datable in tabview. On the first page its all working correctly and i can edit the table, but after i switch the tabs, the datatable isnt editable anymore.
Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Using Primefaces 5.3

```
<h:form id="form">
                        <p:tabView id="tabs" value="#{studentsTableView.exams}" activeIndex="#{studentsTableView.activTab}" dynamic="true" var="exam" binding="#{tabView}" cache="false" >
                         <p:ajax event="tabChange" update="form:tabs" />
                        <p:tab id="tab" title="#{exam.name}">
                            <p:dataTable id="students" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" var="student" editable="true"  widgetVar="gradetable" editMode="cell" tableStyle="width:auto"  styleClass="myTable" value="#{studentsTableView.students}">                    
                                <p:ajax event="cellEdit" update="students"  />
                                <p:column headerText="Nr">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Vorname">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{student.vorname}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Nachname">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{student.nachname}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Matrikelnummer">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{student.matrikelnummer}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:columns value="#{exam.allExams}" var="subexam" columnIndexVar="colIndex">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{subexam.examName}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <p:cellEditor>
                                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText id="modeloutput" value="#{studentsTableView.getGrade(subexam, student)}" /></f:facet>
                                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput"  value="#{studentsTableView.currentGrade}" valueChangeListener="#{studentsTableView.insertGrade(subexam, student)}" style="width:90%"> 
                                                <p:ajax event="change" update="modelInput" />
                                                <p:ajax event="change" update="modeloutput" />
                                                 <p:ajax event="change" update="modeloutput" />
                                                  <p:ajax event="change" update=":form:tabs:0:students" />
                                            </p:inputText></f:facet>
                                    </p:cellEditor>
                                </p:columns>
                                <p:column id="endgrades" headerText="Endnote">
                                    <h:outputText id="endgrade" value="#{studentsTableView.getEndGrade(exam, student)}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Formel">
                                    <p:selectBooleanButton id="value1" value="true" onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No" style="width:60px" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Kommentar">
                                    <p:commandButton id="public" icon="ui-icon-comment" type="button" >
                                        <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{studentsTableView.setPublicCommentInfos(exam, student)}" update="publicarea" />
                                        </p:commandButton>
                                    <p:overlayPanel id="imagePanel" for="public" hideEffect="fade">
                                        <h:inputTextarea id="publicarea" value="#{studentsTableView.publicComment}" >
                                            <p:ajax event="change" update="publicarea" />
                                        </h:inputTextarea>
                                    </p:overlayPanel>
                                    <p:commandButton id="private" icon="ui-icon-locked" type="button" >
                                    <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{studentsTableView.setPrivateCommentInfos(exam, student)}" update="privatearea" />
                                     </p:commandButton>
                                    <p:overlayPanel id="privatepanel" for="private" hideEffect="fade">
                                          <h:inputTextarea id="privatearea" value="#{studentsTableView.privateComment}" >
                                            <p:ajax event="change" update="privatearea" />
                                        </h:inputTextarea>
                                    </p:overlayPanel>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                        </p:tab>
                        </p:tabView>
                    </h:form>
```

Comment: Where is your code going?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be because you're still referencing the datatable id from the first tab, even though you switched to another. You could try to create a different id for each datatable from each tab and then working with those ids and updating them.